# Android with Unity3d Object OnClickListener

Tags: android, events, unity-game-engine

I am an Unity3d beginner.
I wrote a sample Unity3D project and exported it as an Android project.

**How can I trigger  a click event on an Unity3D Object?**

The Unity3D game has lots of objects.
When I click an object, I want to do something in my Android project.

Input.GetTouch is an Unity3D event.
I want use the Android OnClick event instead of that.

How should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the [IPointerClickHandler](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) interface on your MonoBehaviour and ensure that you have instance of EventSystem and a relevant subclass of  [BaseRaycaster](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.BaseRaycaster.html) (3d or 2d, depending what you want to use) present in the scene.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Raycast to for this. As Example here

Attach collider and tag to object you want to add click event and then do this in Update function script

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);
if(hit.collider.tag == "tag"){
// object clicked
// do your work here
}
```