# how to detect a touch on 3d object in unity3d for android device C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am beginner in unity3d i want how to detect touch on game object in 3d mobile game. I am using multiple game objects

Comment: Do you mean touch as in "the player touched the screen over the object" or touch as in "to objects in the game touched each other"

Comment: touch the screen over object

Answer (score 0):

Use the Collider class; from the Unity Scripting API: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html
More specifically, if you want to detect a collision, use Collider.OnCollisionEnter: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html
Also, if you want to cause events when objects touch, one must be set to a trigger, and to detect when a trigger is 'touched,' use OnTriggerEnter, more details on which you can find from the first link.

Comment: Note, this only answers the "two objects in the game touched each other" question, it does not answer the  "the player touched the screen over the object" question

Comment: That question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738868/android-with-unity3d-object-onclicklistener?rq=1

Comment: The OP has clarified in a comment, your answer is no longer relevent.